# How can i do this in c arrays?

Tags: arrays, c

3 arrays of size 3x3 with integer data will be defined. The first two arrays will be filled with random numbers, while the elements of the 3rd array will be the sum of the elements of these two arrays (eg result[i][j] = first[i][j] + second[i][j] ). All the latest sequences will be printed to the screen. How can i do this in c language ?

wrong code:

```
int main () {
    int i,j;
    int a [3][3] ;
    int b [3][3]  ;
    int c [3][3] =  {a [3][3] +   b [3][3]};
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf ("\nElements of array are:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(j=0; j<3; j++){

            a[i][j]=rand()%10+1;
            b[i][j]=rand()%10+1;
            printf ("\n",a[i][j],b[i][j],c[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you see how you're randomizing `a` and `b` right now? And you're doing the same for `c`, except you already gave the formula for how you want `c` to be calculated. Read your question, then read your code.

Comment: sayın, `a [3][3]` in `{a [3][3] +   b [3][3]}` attempts to access `a[][]` outside its range leading to _undefined behavior_.  Why does code attempt this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a revised code (haven't run it)
Added some comments for the few changes i made.

```
int main ()
{
    int a [3][3];
    int b [3][3];
    int c [3][3]; //removed initialization

    srand(time(NULL));
    printf ("\nElements of array are:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
            b[i][j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j]; //do the sum here
            printf ("%d, %d, %d\n",a[i][j],b[i][j],c[i][j]); //added formating to printf
        } 
     }
}
```